# Binding in ControlsTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i have a next control - Calendar. Which i got from nuget WPControls.
I modified it, because i needed a button - Today.

Here is a XAML code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CalendarControlTemplate1"  TargetType="wpControls:Calendar">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Height="auto" Background="Black">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding YearMonthLabel}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button 
                Content="&lt;" 
                Width="100" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="PreviousMonthButton" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Visibility="{Binding ShowNavigationButtons, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                <Button 
                Content="&gt;" 
                Width="100" 
                Grid.Column="2" 
                x:Name="NextMonthButton" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Visibility="{Binding ShowNavigationButtons, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TodayButton" Content="{Binding Path=ButtonName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Tap="Button_Tap" />

                <Grid Height="auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="ItemsGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Sunday}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Monday}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tuesday}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Wednesday}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Thursday}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Friday}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="6"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Saturday}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="7"/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I have added this thing:

```
<Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TodayButton" Content="{Binding Path=ButtonName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Tap="Button_Tap" />
```

I want it to change it's content, e.g. text when i switch languages, so i have done this binding:

```
Content="{Binding Path=ButtonName}"
```

But it doesn't work, why? and how to fix it?

Here is my C# code:

```
string ButtonName;
public CalendarPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonName = GS.translations["Today"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg said, you need to have a data context which implements INotifyPropertyChange.
There's another dirty way.Hope that works.
1) Change your code something like this

```
public string ButtonName{get;set;}
public CalendarPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonName = GS.translations["Today"];
    }
```

2) And your Xaml somthing like this

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=YourUserControlName,Path=ButtonName}"
```

Comment: have you given your username a key ? like x:Name or x:key ? that should be applied to 'YourUserControlName'

Comment: Yes. it looks like this:

<Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TodayButton" Content="{Binding ElementName=TodayButton,Path=ButtonName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Tap="Button_Tap" />

Comment: Nope. it would be your control name which hosts your Button. Lets say if it is a Window <Window x:Name="myWindow"> <Button .../></Window>.. than content would be Content="{Binding ElementName=myWindow,Path=ButtonName}"

Comment: Give your Window a x:Name and replace "YourUserControlName" with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement INPC (INotifyPropertyChanged) and then fire the PropertyChanged event.  This will update the button.

This is getting into the realm of MVVM and there are many such frameworks to help you do this.

Greg